# Find un-referenced variables in xml through XPath

Tags: xpath

The following XML structure is an example of metadata of a given screen:

```
<page>
    <context>
        <variable name="used" type="String" />
        <variable name="unused" type="String" />
        <variable name="temp" type="Number" />
    </context>
    <actions>
        <assign>
             <from>"Test"</from>
             <to>used</to>
        </assign>
        <assign>
             <from>1</from>
             <to>temp</to>
        </assign>
    </actions>
 </page>
```

I'm looking for an XPath expression that can return me a list of variables that are un-referenced in the page. In this example, it is the **unused** variable.

Given that:

```
not(/page/actions//*/text() = 'unused') => Returns true (unreferenced)
not(/page/actions//*/text() = 'used') => Returns false
```

and

```
/page/context/variable[not(/page/actions//*/text() = @name)] => Return unused variable node
/page/context/variable[/page/actions//*/text() = @name] => Returns the used and temp variable node
```

this all works as long as the text exactly matches the name of the variable. However, as the text is an expression, it can contain more than just the variable name and in any place in the string.

So I thought of using the **contains(haystack, needle)** to do the same as above.

Given that:

```
/page/actions//*[contains(text() , 'temp')] => Returns the temp variable node
not(/page/actions//*[contains(text() , 'unused')]) => Returns true
```

I thought that one of these would work:

```
/page/context/variable[not(/page/actions//*[contains(text(), @name)])]
```

I assume @name doesn't work as it's not in the scope of the variable node, but the one from //*

nor does

```
/page/context/variable[not(contains(/page/actions//*/text(), @name))]
```

which returns all 3 variables.

Can anyone guide me as to:

1. Why does it work with equality and not with the contains?
2. What expression would return me the correct result?

Ideally, this is achieved by using version 1.0 of the XPath specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it works with equality is that your predicate is filtering the `/page/context/variable` elements, so `@name` is referencing that variable element's attribute, and the `=` is a set comparison that can test whether any of the (multiple) `/page/actions//text()` node values are equal to the (single) `@name`.

There are two issues with the XPath that you were attempting to use `contains()` with:

1. Within the predicate filter on the action elements, `@name` would resolve to be the name attribute of the context element that the predicate is filtering. It doesn't know that you are referring to the name attribute of the `/page/context/variable` elements.
2. There can be multiple `text()`, and `contains()` expects a single item for the first parameter.

With **XPath 2.0** or greater, you could use the following XPath, which binds the `@name` to a variable and then tests whether any of the `text()` node descendants of `/page/actions` contain the variable `$name` value.

```
/page/context/variable[
  let $name := @name 
  return not(/page/actions//*/text()[contains(., $name)]) 
]
```

Comment: So, you don't see a way to achieve this through XPath 1.0 only?

Comment: How are you executing the XPath? XSLT? With a single XPath 1.0 expression it may not be possible, but you could bind variables and use multiple XPath 1.0 statements coordinated by the host engine and its language constructs (XSLT, Java, PHP, JavaScript, etc.)